# Tic-Tac-Toe in C (Using a 2D Character Array)

Tags: c, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I have looked over the various other posts considering how to implement Tic-Tac-Toe in C but am unfortunately running into issues. I have two functions for initialising and drawing the grid, `int init_grid(int gridsize)` and `void draw_grid(int gridsize)`. These take the parameter `gridsize` as the user is able to choose from a 3x3 to a 10x10 grid. The program compiles far so far, but when entering the size of the board, it prints the correct number of '.' characters but only in the first column.

The code is as follows:

**init_grid**

```
int init_grid(int gridsize) {


for (int row = 0; row < gridsize ; row++) {

    for (int col = 0; col < gridsize; col++) {
        grid[row][col] = '.';
    }
}

if (gridsize > MaxGrid) {
    puts("Error, gridsize too large.");
    return 1;
}

else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**draw_grid**

```
void draw_grid(int gridsize) {

for (int row = 0; row < gridsize; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; row < gridsize; row++)
    {   
        putchar (' ');
        if (grid[row][col]) {
            putchar (grid[row][col]);
        }
        else {
            putchar ('.');
        }

    printf("\n");
   }
  }
 }
```

**main**

```
int main() {

int gridsize = 0;

printf("Hello and welcome to Tic Tac Toe\n");
printf("Please enter the size of the grid you would like to play with (between 3 and 10):\n");
scanf("%d", &gridsize);

init_grid(gridsize);
draw_grid(gridsize);

return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello and welcome to Tic Tac Toe
Please enter the size of the grid you would like to play with (between 3 and 
10):
 5
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

[image: Desired output]

I hope I have made everything clear enough. I've tried a variety of different things now but just can't get it to print the board/grid correctly.

Comment: In `draw_grid` function the loop `for (int col = 0; row < gridsize; row++)` is a victim of copy/paste. Change the two occurrences of `row` to `col`.

Comment: Also `printf("\n");` should be moved after the column for loop scope ends.

Comment: What is the desired output? Please update the question to include what the expected output is.

Comment: Good spot, thanks for that. I amended it and now the output prints the correct number of '.' characters (25), but still all in the same first column like my original output

Comment: Note that `init_grid()` should test the argument *before* it uses it.

Comment: where is the grid ?

Comment: @Chimera I've updated the post. There is a link to the image of what I want.

Comment: @Imran Thank you. That has printed the grid just fine. Much appreciated>

Now to think of a way to have the board size with the index's printed according to gridsize like shown in my desired output.

Comment: `puts("Error, gridsize too large.");` is incorrect.  You are printing an error message, and you should get in the habit of always printing error messages to stderr: `fputs("Error...", stderr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above are all correct. I've put all the corrected code below and now the code does as expected.

I also added the code to label the rows and columns. Note that changes need to be made when the gridsize is greater than 9.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int init_grid(int gridsize);
void draw_grid(int gridsize);

char grid[25][25];
int MaxGrid = 25;


int init_grid(int gridsize)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < gridsize ; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < gridsize; col++)
        {
            grid[row][col] = '.';
        }
    }

    if (gridsize > MaxGrid)
    {
        puts("Error, gridsize too large.");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


void draw_grid(int gridsize)
{

    printf("    ");
    for( int i=0; i < gridsize; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d ", i+1);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int row = 0; row < gridsize; row++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", row+1);
        for (int col = 0; col < gridsize; col++)
        {   
            putchar (' ');
            if (grid[row][col])
            {
                putchar (grid[row][col]);
            }
            else
            {
                putchar ('.');
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main()
{

    int gridsize = 0;

    printf("Hello and welcome to Tic Tac Toe\n");
    printf("Please enter the size of the grid you would like to play with (between 3 and 10):\n");
    scanf("%d", &gridsize);

    init_grid(gridsize);
    draw_grid(gridsize);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ ./a.out 
Hello and welcome to Tic Tac Toe
Please enter the size of the grid you would like to play with (between 3 and 10):
5
    1 2 3 4 5 
1   . . . . .
2   . . . . .
3   . . . . .
4   . . . . .
5   . . . . .
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ ./a.out 
Hello and welcome to Tic Tac Toe
Please enter the size of the grid you would like to play with (between 3 and 10):
3
    1 2 3 
1   . . .
2   . . .
3   . . .
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ ./a.out 
Hello and welcome to Tic Tac Toe
Please enter the size of the grid you would like to play with (between 3 and 10):
10
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1   . . . . . . . . . .
2   . . . . . . . . . .
3   . . . . . . . . . .
4   . . . . . . . . . .
5   . . . . . . . . . .
6   . . . . . . . . . .
7   . . . . . . . . . .
8   . . . . . . . . . .
9   . . . . . . . . . .
10   . . . . . . . . . .
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it's hugely appreciated!

Comment: @GeorgeStrawbridge You're welcome. If this answered your question(s), please mark it as the solution. Regards.